# jquery validation on IE8 skips all the rules and executes the submithandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a tool which contains a number of forms and I am using jquery(1.11.3) validate plugin(1.14.0) for validation. Its working well with all the browsers - Chrome, FF, IE9 & above.

On IE8, the rules are all skipped and it directly executes the code which is inside the submithandler.

I cannot use jquery lesser than 1.9 as I use bootstrap 3.

Need help on fixing this issue.

A sample code:

`$("#additionalDetailsForm").validate({
            rules : {
                aadhaarNum : {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 12
                },
                passportNum : {
                    required: true,
                    passport : "Invalid Passport Number (X0000000)"
                }
            },
            messages : {
                aadhaarNum : {
                    digits : "Aadhaar number invalid (only numbers)",
                    minlength : "Aadhaar number invalid (12 digits)"
                }
            },
            submitHandler : handleSubmitForEachForm
        });`

One important thing can be that I am loading the HTML of the form using AJAX and then in the success of the AJAX the HTML is appended to the DOM, after which I run the above code to bind the validation to the form.

Comment: It looks like a bug in validation plugin itself. I opened the demo page of the  jqueryvalidation.org in IE8 and observed the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issueby downgrading the jquery.validate.js version to 1.11.0. Source of the solution - https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/795#issuecomment-126140808

From the issue-795

> I was using the validation v1.11.1
>   (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/1.11.1) in my
>   project but when I tested at IE8, the submitHandler function runs ok
>   but it doesn't validate the fields then, the form submit is executed.
>
> Also, using the v1.11.0
>   (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/1.11.0), the
>   form is correctly validated at IE8.